# Iterar arreglo dentro de una consulta LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Alguien me puede ayudar con lo siguiente por favor:

Estoy creando un método que consulta una serie de datos y necesito hacer la búsqueda con base en una cadena de texto ingresada, posterior al ingreso de la cadena debo separar la cadena por palabras y guardarla en un arreglo de string, en la consulta LINQ debo buscar registros que coincidan con la cantidad de palabras que hay en ese arreglo string. por ejemplo: si ingreso San Antoni, debo buscar coincidencias en la base de datos que tenga la palabra San Y la palabra Antonio (No importa si hay registros que cuentan con más palabras pero debe cumplir sí o sí con que tenga por lo menos esas dos para este ejemplo, es decir, si hay un registro que diga San Antonio de Pereira, debería retornarlo, si hay un registro San Agustín, no debería retornarlo). El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
List<DireccionNombrada> direccionesNombradas = new List<DireccionNombrada>();

        char delimitador = ' ';

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoFiltroDireccion.Nombre))
        {
            infoFiltroDireccion.Nombre = "";
        }

        string[] palabras = infoFiltroDireccion.Nombre.Split(delimitador);

        direccionesNombradas.AddRange((from direccionNombrada in _direccionNombradaRepositorio.GetAll()
                                        join direccion in _direccionRepositorio.GetAll() on direccionNombrada.DireccionId equals direccion.Id
                                        where ((!palabras.Any() || (direccionNombrada.Nombre.ToUpper().Contains(palabra.ToUpper())))
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.PaisId.HasValue || direccion.Barrio.Localidad.Departamento.Pais.Id == infoFiltroDireccion.PaisId)
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.DepartamentoId.HasValue || direccion.Barrio.Localidad.Departamento.Id == infoFiltroDireccion.DepartamentoId)
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.LocalidadId.HasValue || direccion.Barrio.Localidad.Id == infoFiltroDireccion.LocalidadId)
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.TorieLocalidad1Id.HasValue || direccion.TorieLocalidad1Id == infoFiltroDireccion.TorieLocalidad1Id)
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.Orientacion1.HasValue || direccion.Orientacion1 == infoFiltroDireccion.Orientacion1)
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.SufijoLocalidad1Id.HasValue || direccion.SufijoLocalidad1Id == infoFiltroDireccion.SufijoLocalidad1Id)
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.TorieLocalidad2Id.HasValue || direccion.TorieLocalidad2Id == infoFiltroDireccion.TorieLocalidad2Id)
                                                && (!infoFiltroDireccion.SufijoLocalidad2Id.HasValue || direccion.SufijoLocalidad2Id == infoFiltroDireccion.SufijoLocalidad2Id)
                                                && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoFiltroDireccion.ZipCode) || direccion.ZipCode == infoFiltroDireccion.ZipCode)))
                                        select direccionNombrada).ToList());

        return direccionesNombradas.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada, te recomiendo usar la sintáxis de LINQ usando expresiones Lambda, me parece mucho más práctica.
Aquí te dejo el código para encontrar los ítems cuyos nombres incluyan *todas* las palabras incluidas en la búsqueda, como estás necesitando.

```
List<DireccionNombrada> items = _direccionNombradaRepositorio.GetAll()

string[] palabras = infoFiltroDireccion.Nombre.ToUpper().Split(delimitador);

List<DireccionNombrada> resultados = items.Where(x => palabras.All(y => y.Contains(x.Nombre.ToUpper()))).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Explicandote un poco qué es lo que hace el código LINQ ...

1. Primero se ejecuta el método Where para filtrar los datos en base a una condición (tal cual como lo haría un `WHERE` en SQL). La condición es la expresón lambda "`y => y.Contains(x.Nombre.ToUpper())))`.
2. La condición está diciendo "incluye todos los elementos dentro de la colección "items" en la que se de como cierto que *todos* (`All`) los valores del array "palabras" estén contenidos dentro de la propiedad "Nombre" del elemento `DireccionNombrada` siendo evaluado.
3. Finalmente, se ejecuta el método `Select()` que lo que hace es decir "ok, con el resultado este filtrado qué hago?" El `Select` le indica que lo devuelva ( análogo al SELECT de SQL ) incluyendo las propiedades (columnas, en SQL) que se especifiquen. Al hacer `Select(x => x)` es lo mismo que en SQL logramos con un "*SELECT * FROM ..*". Si se hubiese querido sólo algunas columnas, se podría haber hecho `.Select(x => x.Propiedad1, x.Propiedad2)`